# What order does the word 'just' follow?

Tags: adverbs, word-order

I had an exercise in my English lesson.It says to choose the suitable choice.I think that I do not make any wrong.

> The living room needs repainting and I don't have enough time ~ *Why don't you just have someone do it then?*

I know how adverbs ordering in sentences.However, the 'just' can take the position before 
an auxiliary verb.

e.g. I just do not understand why it happened

My question is when someone ask, how the above sentence become?

Why do you just not focus on the relation between...Is it correct?

Can the first sentence writing in formal

> Why do you just not have someone does it then?

Comment: The living room needs repainting and I don't have enough time. - Why don't you just get someone else to do it then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adverbs are tricky and their placement is trickier! In many instances, words like *'only', 'just'* etc. change the meaning of the sentence depending on their placement. Let's take 'only' first.

> New software ***just confused*** the PA = It did not do anything other than 'confusing' her.

But if you say...

> New software confused ***just the PA*** = If confused just the PA but no any other person from the office staff.

Likewise, if you want to emphasize that you just get *someone else* do the job, placement is correct this way -

> Why don't you ***just get/have someone else*** to do it

Though the overall meaning may remain same in *this particular sentence*, placing it before the auxiliary verb there would relate 'just' with auxiliary verb.

Furthermore, if you place the adverb somewhere else, it'd again change the meaning

> Why don't you get/have someone else ***just to do it***

Again, depending on the placement, it'd mean that you appoint someone *just* to do that work and nothing else.